# Grails Spring Security RequestMap not matching /

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

My app has this url mapping:

```
"/"(controller: 'app', action: 'index')
```

And I'm using a domain class to store RequestMap instances in the database.
The access to app/index is restricted to certain roles, so when a user hits / or /app/index, the login form is shown.

When a user, that has permissions to see / or /app/index logs in, the app is showing a message: **"Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page."**, so for some reason Spring Security is not considering my RequestMaps.

I tried a lot of combinations, maybe I'm missing something. What I have right now is (Bootstrap.groovy):

```
 new RequestMap(url: '/', configAttribute: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save()
 new RequestMap(url: '/app/index', configAttribute: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save()
 new RequestMap(url: '/**', configAttribute: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save()
```

The user I'm using to login has ROLE_ADMIN assigned, this is the console log on login:

```
userDetails grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@586034f:
Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true;
credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN
auth com.cabolabs.security.UserPassOrgAuthToken@40a3c9e2:
Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@586034f:
Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true;
credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN;
Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN
```

FYI, I customized the login to use user+pass+organization, that's why there is a UserPassOrgAuthToken instead of the standard UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

**Edit**

I also have rejectIfNoRule = true and defaultTargetUrl = '/app/index', not sure if this is affecting anything:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/app/index' // "/" is mapped to "/app/index"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I can't secure "/", googling for days and there are no examples of securing "/".

What I did was:

1. change the mappging from "/" to "/app/index" for "/" to "/login"
2. keep the just new RequestMap(url: '/app/index', configAttribute: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save()

So, accessing to the app without being logged in, redirects me to "/login".
If I access to "/" being logged in, it redirects to "/app/index" (defaultTargetUrl).

This is the expected behavior but I had to remove my requirement of showing a dashboard when the user access to my web root "/", now my users see "/app/index" instead of "/" in the URL.